# Javascript remote events?

Tags: javascript, http, events

Is it possible to have a web service notify web clients when something occurs via HTTP request/response? Right now my client has to poll the server using HTTP Requests at an interval to check for updates, but it would be far more convenient if I could register a javascript function to the server from my client and have it be simply called when server state changes.

Note that the web service is written in Python and utilizes HTTP APIs (I think it uses cherrypy, if that's relevant).

If this is possible could someone point me to some tutorial that explains how to do this or give me a basic understanding of how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can't start a request from the server to the client. You can only poll the server (which you did), use a hidden iframe, use a plugin, or use the new HTML5 [WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) which allows the server to send a message to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into Node.JS, look into socket.io and hook.io

https://github.com/hookio

https://socket.io